# CodenameOne with Eclipse: send Android build failed

Tags: android, eclipse, codenameone

when i try to send my app for Android build i get this error from console:

> Buildfile: /run/media/giuseppe/KINGSTON/_Sviluppo/Android/iPhone-WPhone/_codename_projects/MadonnaDiFatimaTrapani/build.xml
>
> copy-android-override:
>
> copy-libs:
>
> jar:
>        [echo] Compile is forcing compliance to the supported API's/features for maximum device compatibility. This allows smaller
>        [echo]           code size and wider device support
>        [copy] Copying 3 files to /run/media/giuseppe/KINGSTON/_Sviluppo/Android/iPhone-WPhone/_codename_projects/MadonnaDiFatimaTrapani/build/tmp
>        [copy] Updating the file: /run/media/giuseppe/KINGSTON/_Sviluppo/Android/iPhone-WPhone/_codename_projects/MadonnaDiFatimaTrapani/CodeNameOneBuildClient.jar
>        [copy] Updating the file: /run/media/giuseppe/KINGSTON/_Sviluppo/Android/iPhone-WPhone/_codename_projects/MadonnaDiFatimaTrapani/lib/CLDC11.jar
>       [javac] Compiling 1 source file to /run/media/giuseppe/KINGSTON/_Sviluppo/Android/iPhone-WPhone/_codename_projects/MadonnaDiFatimaTrapani/build/tmp
>       [javac] Updating the file: /run/media/giuseppe/KINGSTON/_Sviluppo/Android/iPhone-WPhone/_codename_projects/MadonnaDiFatimaTrapani/lib/CodenameOne.jar
>       [javac] error: error reading /run/media/giuseppe/KINGSTON/_Sviluppo/Android/iPhone-WPhone/_codename_projects/MadonnaDiFatimaTrapani/lib/CodenameOne.jar; error in opening zip file
>       [javac] 1 error
>
> BUILD FAILED
>   /run/media/giuseppe/KINGSTON/_Sviluppo/Android/iPhone-WPhone/_codename_projects/MadonnaDiFatimaTrapani/build.xml:147:
>   Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
>
> Total time: 2 seconds

Are my jars corrupted? because i had installed zip editor plugin. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably because of a bad update in the new [Update Client Framework](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/new-update-framework.html).

Try running update client libs which you can launch via the right client Codename One -> Codename One Settings -> Basic form.

I'm assuming you are using the latest 3.8.3 plugin.

If you understand how this state was reached it's probably worthwhile filing an issue on that with a way to reproduce.

Comment: yes i've the 3.8.3 plugin on Eclipse neon.3 (4.6.3). Updated the client libs now works, thanks. About reproduction, I don't remember well how this situation was generated.

Comment: I really wish that there was a way to update libs without going to settings . It gets blocked by my firewall and I have to wait to go home each day I want to do this

Comment: Can't you configure a proxy? Notice that we should respect the proxy you define in the simulator, just run an app and in the simulator under Network define the proxy settings